# Debugging NetworkD3 graphs

Tags: r, graph, data-visualization, nodes, networkd3

I tried following this tutorial over here (2nd part) on making network graphs in R: https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/

```
# Load data
library(networkD3)
data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

# Plot
forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes,
            Source = "source", Target = "target",
            Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
            Group = "group", opacity = 0.8)
```

Yet, when I tried the same on my data it does not work (it produces an empty image):

```
Data_I_Have <- data.frame(
   
    "Node_A" = c("John", "John", "John", "Peter", "Peter", "Peter", "Tim", "Kevin", "Adam", "Adam", "Xavier"),
    "Node_B" = c("Claude", "Peter", "Tim", "Tim", "Claude", "Henry", "Kevin", "Claude", "Tim", "Henry", "Claude"),
    " Place_Where_They_Met" = c("Chicago", "Boston", "Seattle", "Boston", "Paris", "Paris", "Chicago", "London", "Chicago", "London", "Paris"),
  "Years_They_Have_Known_Each_Other" = c("10", "10", "1", "5", "2", "8", "7", "10", "3", "3", "5"),
  "What_They_Have_In_Common" = c("Sports", "Movies", "Computers", "Computers", "Video Games", "Sports", "Movies", "Computers", "Sports", "Sports", "Video Games")
)


links = data.frame(Data_I_Have$Node_A, Data_I_Have$Node_B)
links$value =1
links$source = Data_I_Have$Node_A
links$target = Data_I_Have$Node_B
links$Node_A = NULL
links$Node_B = NULL
links = links[,c(3,4,5)]

nodes = data.frame( "Node_A" = c("John", "Peter", "Tim", "Kevin", "Adam", "Xavier", "Claude", "Henry"))
nodes$group =1
nodes$name = nodes$Node_A
nodes$Node_A = NULL


# Plot
forceNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
            Source = "source", Target = "target",
            Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
            Group = "group", opacity = 0.8)
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

help file says:

> Links:  a data frame object with the links between the nodes. It should include the Source and Target for each link. These should be numbered starting from 0. An optional Value variable can be included to specify how close the nodes are to one another.

your links data frame:

```
str(links)

'data.frame':   11 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ value : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ source: chr  "John" "John" "John" "Peter" ...
 $ target: chr  "Claude" "Peter" "Tim" "Tim" ...
```

source and target columns must be numeric

Answer (score 0):

Given your `links` and `nodes` data frames, you can add the zero-based index of each node in the `nodes` data frame to the `links` data frame like this, and then reference the names of the columns in your `links` data frame that contain the zero-based indexes in the `forceNetwork()` function...

```r
tibble::as_tibble(links)
#> # A tibble: 11 × 3
#>    value source target
#>    <dbl> <chr>  <chr> 
#>  1     1 John   Claude
#>  2     1 John   Peter 
#>  3     1 John   Tim   
#>  4     1 Peter  Tim   
#>  5     1 Peter  Claude
#>  6     1 Peter  Henry 
#>  7     1 Tim    Kevin 
#>  8     1 Kevin  Claude
#>  9     1 Adam   Tim   
#> 10     1 Adam   Henry 
#> 11     1 Xavier Claude

tibble::as_tibble(nodes)
#> # A tibble: 8 × 2
#>   group name  
#>   <dbl> <chr> 
#> 1     1 John  
#> 2     1 Peter 
#> 3     1 Tim   
#> 4     1 Kevin 
#> 5     1 Adam  
#> 6     1 Xavier
#> 7     1 Claude
#> 8     1 Henry 


links$source_id <- match(links$source, nodes$name) - 1
links$target_id <- match(links$target, nodes$name) - 1

tibble::as_tibble(links)
#> # A tibble: 11 × 5
#>    value source target source_id target_id
#>    <dbl> <chr>  <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1     1 John   Claude         0         6
#>  2     1 John   Peter          0         1
#>  3     1 John   Tim            0         2
#>  4     1 Peter  Tim            1         2
#>  5     1 Peter  Claude         1         6
#>  6     1 Peter  Henry          1         7
#>  7     1 Tim    Kevin          2         3
#>  8     1 Kevin  Claude         3         6
#>  9     1 Adam   Tim            4         2
#> 10     1 Adam   Henry          4         7
#> 11     1 Xavier Claude         5         6

forceNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
             Source = "source_id", Target = "target_id",
             Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
             Group = "group", opacity = 0.8)
```